# If mean is equal to standard deviation , then the distribution is always an exponential distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, standard-deviation, means, exponential-distribution

I am unable to define skewness and kurtosis, only with mean and standard deviation. Can we say, if the distribution has mean and standard deviation, which is equal to each other, is it an exponential distribution?

Comment: An exponential distribution's skewness & kurtosis are both definable.

Comment: An interesting point is that if $E[X-k\mid X>k] =\sqrt{Var(X-k \mid X>k)}$ for all $k \ge 0$ - in a sense a [memoryless property for the shape of the distribution](http://www.se16.info/hgb/shape-memoryless.pdf) -  then I think that the distribution or at least its positive part  is always exponential

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Starting from any distribution with a finite standard deviation, you can translate it by a constant (which does not change the standard deviation) to make its mean equal the standard deviation; this is clearly not going to be an exponential distribution in general.